# SqliteException (0x80004005): SQLite Error 6: database table is locked - in-memory database with one writer thread and many query threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, sqlite, sqlite-net

I have a .NET server application running on RHEL (don't ask...) using SQLite as an in-memory database.

A single writer thread is updating a bunch of tables using an explicit transaction with external data and then repeats the same after waiting about a second. At the same time I have a bunch of read-only worker threads querying data in the tables concurrently. The queries are all running fairly quickly (~20ms).

All threads/connections use the same connection string: "Data Source=INTERNAL;Mode=Memory;Cache=Shared" with the read-only worker threads additionally executing a "PRAGMA query_only=true". I tried to make sure all commands/data readers are disposed off at once.

This is mostly working fine but occasionally I get a "Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException (0x80004005): SQLite Error 6: database table is locked" in the writer thread after what appears to be a 30 second (default ?) time out when the code tries to run an UPDATE command using ExecuteNonQuery. When it happens the error could be on any of the tables being updated in the transaction.

Exception is thrown on:

```
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException.ThrowExceptionForRC(Int32 rc, sqlite3 db)
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteDataReader.NextResult()
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at (my code)
```

This looks to me like somehow the read-only worker threads manage to create locks (unexpected) and don't release them (?) which then make the writer thread transaction fail. Subsequent writes from the same writer thread on the same set of tables in a new transaction seem to work fine too.

Currently using Microsoft.Data.Sqlite version 5.0.8

Any ideas what I can do to investigate this further or (even better) fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be an issue when sharing a (read-only) Sqlite connection between multiple threads. Creating separate connections for each of the threads made the issue go away.